XML Parsing getting string inside brakets <something="How to get this string">
Here is a sample of the XML data I am trying to parse. Im having trouble figuring out how to parse the data inside the "" that is nested within the brackets i.e <something="How to get this string">. here for example id want to get "How to get this string". I am able to get the Data if its in between the opening and closing carrots I Got this.
<METAR>
   <sky_condition sky_cover="OVC" cloud_base_ft_agl="2100"/> <---- get the OVC from sky_cover
   <flight_category>IFR</flight_category>
   <metar_type>METAR</metar_type>
</METAR>


Here is my XML Parser Code & Delegate functions
import Foundation

class FeedParser: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    private var airportItems: [FlightCategory] = [] // track parsing
    private var currentAirportElement: String = "" // track current item being parsed
    private var parserCompletiongHandler: (([FlightCategory]) -> Void)? // handle completion of parsing
    
    private var currentAirportFlightCategory: String = "" {
        didSet {
            // trim whitespace
            currentAirportFlightCategory = currentAirportFlightCategory.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
    }
    
    private var currenAirportSkyCondition: String = "" {
        didSet {
            currenAirportSkyCondition = currenAirportSkyCondition.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - URL Request
    
    // Hnadle Parsing feed
    func parseFeed(url: String, completionHandler: (([FlightCategory]) -> Void)?) {
        self.parserCompletiongHandler = completionHandler
        
        // URL Session Reques
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            // if no data
            guard let data = data else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                return
            }
            
            // if data
            // parse xml data
            let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
    // MARK: - XML Parser Delegate
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        // track current item
        currentAirportElement = elementName
        if currentAirportElement == "METAR" { // it is there
            // currentAirportElement = ""
            
            currentAirportFlightCategory = ""
            currenAirportSkyCondition = ""
        }
    }
    
    // Once Parser get values of element Handler
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        switch currentAirportElement {
        case "flight_category": currentAirportFlightCategory += string
                
        default: break
        }
    }
    
    // Once Parser at End of element Handler
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "METAR" { // "flight_category"
            let airportItems = FlightCategory(flight_category: currentAirportFlightCategory, sky_condition: currenAirportSkyCondition)
            self.airportItems.append(airportItems)
        }
    }
    
    // Call Completion Handler upon finishing Parsing
    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        parserCompletiongHandler?(airportItems)
    }
    
    // Handle Parsing Errors
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: any Error) {
        print(parseError.localizedDescription)
    }
}

And here is how I am loading the XML
private func loadXMLData() async {
        print("hmmmmm")
        let acwXMLURL = "https://aviationweather.gov/api/data/dataserver?requestType=retrieve&dataSource=metars&stationString=\KVNY&startTime=2024-03-10T21%3A44%3A22Z&format=xml&mostRecent=true"
        
        // parser feeder
        let feeder = FeedParser()
        feeder.parseFeed(url: acwXMLURL) { data in
            self.detaileHomeAirportXML = data
        }
    }
    
    private func handleXMLData() async {
        detaileHomeAirportXML?.forEach { item in
            currentFltCat = item.flight_category
            model.airportFltCat = item.flight_category
            print("XML data handled: \(currentFltCat)")
            
            if currentFltCat == "VFR" {
                color = Color(.green)
            } else if currentFltCat == "MVFR" {
                color = Color(.blue)
            } else if currentFltCat == "IFR" {
                color = Color(.red)
            } else if currentFltCat == "LIFR" {
                color = Color(red: 208 / 255, green: 45 / 255, blue: 208 / 255)
            }
        }
    }


In the didStartElement delegate method, look at the attributes parameter. That dictionary has the data you want. The keys are the attribute names and the values are the attribute values.

Rash, that is what I was thinking, but I can figure out how it would look im stumped on what the code would

See the link I just posted before your reply.

why not use the more modern approach using the JSON data API endpoint.
https://aviationweather.gov/api/data/metar?stationString=\KVNY&startTime=2024-03-10T21%3A44%3A22Z&format=xml&mostRecent=true&format=json
It's so much easier to decode and process, especially using the
more modern async let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url). You would not have to write those hundreds of lines of code to deal with the old XML.

unfortunaly aviatationweather used xml for large cache which is the end result for I can search for available airports. I was using json- but it became a stopping stone because there one value that I cant seem to find via the JSON and that the Flight Category of the airport. Seems its only in XML

The "thing" you are looking for is called an attribute (and the "carrots" are called start and end tags). Once you learn the basic vocabulary, searching for information on google becomes very easy. If you invent your own vocabulary, it's impossible.

Copy that! I forgot a lot of it when i stopped CS - only getting into it I remember how inviting and understanding Stakeover flow was. I do however appreciate you reminding me of what they are called, it will def help!

In the didStartElement delegation function, you receive an attributes dictionary.  This contains the attributes of the tag.
You would write something like -
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
       
        switch(elementName) {
            case "METAR":
                currentAirportFlightCategory = ""
                currenAirportSkyCondition = ""
            case "sky_condition":
                skyCover = attributes["sky_cover"]
                cloudBase = attributes["cloud_base_ft_agl"]
            default:
                print("Ignoring element \(elementName)")
        }
    }

Note that these will be optional strings, so you need to handle that and convert to integer as required.

FYI - there are lots of duplicates for this question.

Probably, but it was easier to write a clear answer that helps the OP than to wade through to find a good dupe.

I tried - there were so many and i know im not helping i couldnt find the answer. I see what you did but im confused how could I update the foundCharacters to then assign currenAirportSkyCondition is = sky_cover value

Got it to work!! Thank you- will mark as answered, just confused- it seems I need to still use the foundCharacters function to asign values not enclosed in the <> is that correct?

Characters outside elements are text blocks, so yes, you need to use didStartElement to identify the current element and then you can use foundCharacters to get the text associated with that element.  There is probably a good reason why JSON is much more popular than XML these days - As WorkingDog pointed out, this service has a JSON endpoint - It will be much much easier to work with that thanks to Swift Codable

I agree it would be, however aviationweather uses xml for large cache files and there are certain attributes that its JSON doent give access to, mainly and Flight Category - which saved me hundreds of lines of code because otherwise i would have to personally define each flight category
